# Target class [Database\Seeders\MockNotification] does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

i am using a seeder class to seed a table in the database

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;
class MockNotification extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        Notification::factory()->times(2)->create();
    }
}
```

i am calling this class in the DatabaseSeeder

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Database\Seeders\NotificationTypeSeeder;
use Database\Seeders\MockNotification;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call([NotificationTypeSeeder::class]);
        $this->call([MockNotification::class]);
    }
}
```

i am getting this error

> Target class [Database\Seeders\MockNotification] does not exist.

while i already imported MockNotification classs in the DatabaseSeeder file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is really simple to solve, you have to have your `MockNotification` class in `LARAVEL_ROOT_FOLDER/database/seeders` and then add this to the top of your class `namespace Database\Seeders;`.

Your `DatabaseSeeder` class should also have `namespace Database\Seeders;`. It is needed for `composer` to do PSR-4 autoloading.

Your seeder should be like:

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class MockNotification extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Notification::factory()->times(2)->create(); // Add this use on top
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code to your answer please

Comment: @needgfasap I updated my answer, remember to check where the file is, share the path please

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the beginning of seeder file

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
```

and then execute following in terminal

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
```

To both files.

It is standard PSR-4.

Comment: i just added  namespace Database\Seeders; to both files here is why i got when i seed the database : Target class [Database\Seeders\MockNotificationSeeder] does not exist.

Comment: Rename MockNotification file to MockNotificationSeeder. In docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding use this agreement.

Comment: already added the namespace Database/Seeders in both files and still getting the same error !